# The tapped on comboBox work incorrectly

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp

I have comboBox with names list . When I try to select a name in the list, it generally takes 3-5 clicks on the selected name.

```
            <ComboBox
            Grid.Row="6"
            Height="50"
            Margin="0,20,0,0"
            Name="AssetClassComboBox"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ListAssetClass, Mode=OneWay}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:ComboBoxAssetClassItem">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="{x:Bind Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

If I delete this code the comboBox works correctly, the list is visible, but I cannot see the names.

```
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:ComboBoxAssetClassItem">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="{x:Bind Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a ItemTemplate you could simply use the property [DisplayMemberPath of ComboBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
<ComboBox 
    ... 
    DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ListAssetClass, Mode=OneWay}">
```